# Error when deleting connections from excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, connection

I have the following code:

```
Sub deletedconns()
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
i = i - 1
Next i
End Sub
```

When I try to use the sub I get this error:

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

The thing is, I either need to delete the connections or be able to change only the path. I tried editing the connections but it also changes the delimiter choice with messes everything up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to step backwards in a loop you go from largest value to smallest. You're trying to force your `i` outside of it's declared range

```
Sub deletedconns()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can also remove your `If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub` line. If `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count = 0` the code won't even enter your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletedconns()

    Dim i As Long '<- You forgot to declare i

    With ThisWorkbook

        For i = .Connections.Count To 1 Step -1 '<- When we delete you good backwards
            'There is no need to check if connections are 0. if are zero the code would not get in the loop
        '                If .Connections.Count = 0 Then
        '                    Exit Sub
        '                Else
        '                    .Connections.Item(i).Delete
        '                End If '<- You forgot end if

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```